# JOIN 2 tables and select specific rows

Tags: java, mysql, wordpress, javafx

I use Wordpress table to populate the javafx TableView.
In WP db I have 2 tables wp_posts & wp_postmeta and I need JOIN the table by ID (post_id in wp_postmeta) and select specific rows from wp_postmeta (not all).

For Exampe:
wp_postmeta structure post_id, meta_key, meta_value. In meta_key there is 3 rows - _yoast_wpseo_title, ._yoast_wpseo_metadesc, ._yoast_wpseo_focuskeywords
and I need this rows value from column meta_value.

My code:

```
ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(" SELECT wp_postmeta._yoast_wpseo_title, wp_postmeta._yoast_wpseo_metadesc, wp_postmeta._yoast_wpseo_focuskeywords, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_name FROM wp_postmeta INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ");
```

And of course I receive error that columns _yoast_wpseo_title, _yoast_wpseo_metadesc, _yoast_wpseo_focuskeywords not found because thay are rows.

How I can do this? (I use java9, javafx, mysql jdbc). Or may be I must use PreparedStatement?

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to filter your query based on the content of the meta_key field, you use a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value, wp_posts.post_title
   FROM wp_postmeta INNER JOIN  wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
   WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key IN ('_yoast_wpseo_title', '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', '_yoast_wpseo_focuskeywords')
```

You are providing a list of the meta keys you want to match. This will give (up to) three rows for each post.

If you want only one row for each post, things get more complicated (and probably aren't worth the trouble). You can use `GROUP BY post_id` and then study the [Aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html).